# Explanation of a Haskell function from an old exam

Tags: function, haskell

I'm reviewing an old exam in my Haskell programming course and I can't seem to wrap my head around this function (I think there is just too little information given).

The code given is

```
myId x = x

function n f
 | n > 0 = f . function (n-1) f
 | otherwise = myId
```

I know that if I for example call the function with the input `2 (*2)`, I will get a function as result. And if I call it with `(-2) (*2) 1` I will get the result `1`.

I just don't know how? Also I can't wrap my head around the typecast of the function.

I know that these two options are correct but I don't understand why (probably parentheses that confuse me at the moment).

```
function :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
function :: (Num a, Ord b) => a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

Anyone that can clarify how I should "read" this function and how I should understand how the typecast works (been reading my Programming in Haskell literature and from Learn You a Haskell but been going in circle for a few days now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function` takes some number `n` and a function `f :: a -> a`, and composes that function with itself `n` times, returning another function of type `a -> a`. When the returned function is applied to a value of type `a`, the result is essentially the same as executing `f` in a loop `n` times, using the output of each previous step as the input for the next.

Perhaps it is easier to see the similarity if the final parameter is made explicit:

```
function :: (Ord a, Num a) -> a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
function n f x
  | n > 0     = f (function (n-1) f x)
  | otherwise = x
```

This is functionally equivalent to your point-free `function`.

In Haskell, a function `f :: a -> b -> c` can be interpreted either as "a function that takes an `a` and a `b` and returns a `c`" or "a function that takes an `a` and returns a function from `b` to `c`". When you apply a function to one or more inputs, think of each input as eliminating one of the function's arguments. In this instance, `function 10` returns a new function with type `(a -> a) -> a -> a`, and `function 2 (*2)` returns a function with type `Num a => a -> a`.

When you think of it this way, it should hopefully be clear why `function (-2) (*2) 1` returns a number while `function 2 (*2)` returns a function. There is no type casting going on; when you are applying the three argument `function` to two inputs, you get another function back instead of a value, since you didn't provide the final input needed to compute that value.

Comment: Thanks alot. Totally get it now(finally the dots are connected :D)

Comment: you haven't explained why the second type is the one that's correct. :)